# Xamarin two collectionviews right after one another without space between them

Tags: xaml, user-interface, xamarin, collectionview

I am trying to display two collection views in a page. I want first collection view displays all of its items and only after the second collection view starts right after end of the first collection view without any space to display its items. The lists are dynamic, each time they may have different number of items.

However when I add the second collection view in the page, the page divided into to two section. How can I achieve what I want. Any help appreciated

[the image shows what is needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LP8ua.png)

Comment: maybe you can use one CollectionView but you group items into 2 groups?

Comment: @Mohammad The CollectionViews contain different kind of items. I also would like to add different headers.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a known issue where the CollectionView takes up too much vertical space. Take a look at the [bug report](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6451) where some users post some potential work arounds.

Comment: Instead of CollectionViews, use StackLayouts with [Bindable Layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts). This is useful when you don't need scrolling inside each list of items. Wrap those StackLayouts inside an outer StackLayout that has `Spacing=0`. If you get this working, consider adding Your Answer below with the code, so others in the future can see the exact details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ToolmakerSteve this solution is acceptable for me.

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
            VerticalOptions="Start" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

        <Label Text="List 1" TextColor="Chocolate"  FontSize="20" Padding="10" />
        <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList1}" >
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>

        <Label Text="List 2" TextColor="Chocolate"  FontSize="20" Padding="10" />
        <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList2}" >
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>         

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```